# Simple expression to limit string count in an attribute field

Tags: arcade

Looking to create an attribute rule to constrain a value in an attribute field to a certain length.  I used to be able to use "stringcount" in VB script to return features of a certain length, but need to come up with an appropriate Arcade function.

This is an example of an attribute rule arcade expression I used to look for null features entered

```
   return !IsEmpty($feature.Name);
```

Using this to help users detect data entry errors with validation rule if they enter in a value that is not equal to nine characters - some semblance of what I have below:

```
  return !StringCount<>9($feature.Name);
```

Perhaps a conditional helper needs to be added with a WHERE statement?

Comment: Have you tried exploring the arcade help file? You will discover many string manipulation functions.

Comment: Are you trying to do this with ArcGIS Pro or another part of the ArcGIS platform?

Comment: Try this: `var x ="wombat";
if (Count(x) >= 9){return true;} else {return false;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it appears you have already worked with attribute rules, e.g., saying you have created and are using validation rules, I won't go into explaining what they are and the mechanics of creating them.

Looking at syntax, the following rule:

```
return (Count(Text($feature.TXT_FLD)) == 9)
```

will force a text field to have nine characters in it.  In theory, you should not need the `Text` call since `Count` can work directly against strings, but I find the expression validator gives false errors if I exclude the `Text` call, and those false errors prevent me from saving the rule.

Comment: Thanks!!!  This helps out a lot!!